# Create table #name; is throwing a syntax error

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

When I use the following query:

```
create table #name;
```

I get the following error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at end of input

I am doing this in RedShift DB

I also tried
"create temporary table #name;" and "create temporary table name;".
I am getting the same error for this query also.

I am trying to create a temporary table here, but I keep getting syntax error

Comment: Please remove the sql-server tag, which refers specifically to the Microsoft SQL Server product, while you're using the Amazon Redshift product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE statement.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE #name (
    id INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html

Comment: We can create a table using the pound. The query needed column names as parameters.

The below query seemed to work fine:
create table #temporary_name(
id INTEGER,
name VARCHAR(255)
);

Answer (score -2):

You must provide the table and columns name, as well as the data types that will be used in it.
For Eg :

```
create table table_name (
column_name data_type,
column_name data_type
);
```

If you specify a table name that begins with '# ', the table is created as a temporary table.

```
 create table #name (
 id INTEGER, 
 name VARCHAR(255)
);
```